# Spring transaction doesn't rollback in classes not instantiated by Spring context

Tags: web-services, spring, transactions, soapui, rollback

I have a problem with handling transaction in Spring.
I have a web service which simply iterates a definite number of times, and each time insert a record into an Oracle db. I marked the insert method of my service as @Transactional, because I want it to rollback whenever any of the insert fails (following a RuntimeException, i.e., in case of null object to be inserted).

The problem is that if I test the service by java, with a main that instantiates the service through the Spring application context, evertything works fine (I get every record rollbacked).
If instead I test the web service with soapUI, after having deployed it on a local server,it's like the @Transactional annotation is not seen.

I report my code.

Here's my service:

```
@Service
public class MyService{

        @Transactional
        public void insert(List<DAO> l) {

              for(DAO item : l) {
              //Insert item into the DB
              //and throw a RunTimeException in case of failure (i.e.,item null)
              }
        }
}
```

Here's my main:

```
public class TestMain{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext ac = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(SPRING_CONTEXT_XML_PATH);

        MyService service = ac.getBean(MyService .class);

        List<DAO> l; //Suppose it is initialized    
        service.insert(l); //Rollback working if RuntimeException is thrown     
}
```

}

As I said, the above code works when I instantiate the web service with Spring application context, but if I call MyService through soapUI after having deployed it on the server (which is actually what the service is done for), the @Transactional is not executed.

Can somebody explain to me this behaviour?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you share SOAP code that calls this web service? How is the endpoint obtaining and calling your `MyService`?

Answer (score 0):

spring starts a transaction for you every time the `insert` method is called, because it has the `@Transactional` annotation. When `insert` returns the transaction is commited (or rolled back if exception was thrown).

when spring creates a bean of type `MyService`, it wraps the `insert` method with something like this:

```
EntityManager em = ...; // get EntityManager here
EntityTransaction tx = null;
try {
    tx = em.getTransaction();
    tx.begin();

    // your insert method is called here.

    tx.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
    if ( tx != null && tx.isActive() ) {
        tx.rollback();
    }
}
```

soupUI does not handle the `@Transactional` annotation. You have to start a transaction and commit/rollback it yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But a deployed service must be called by a remote client (without instantiating the service class in java from a main class), and with soapUI I should test the logic of my service. Who calls the service gets the same behaviour as without the transactional annotation (that means the no rollback will be executed)?